# PHP date is showing different time

Tags: php

In Mysql database, I have 3 column which is bookingDate, bookingTime, bookingTimeEnd.

This 3 fields data are inserted from the HTML form using PHP.  After save to the database the value is:

```
06/01/2018 (variable name $bookingDate)
02:01 (variable name $bookingTime )
04:02 (variable name $bookingTimeEnd)
```

Now, I have converted this `$bookingDate` with `$bookingTime` and 
    `$bookingTimeEnd` variable to save it to another table name.

```
$assignedOn =  strtotime($bookingDate .''. $bookingTime);
$assignedEnd =  strtotime($bookingDate .''. $bookingTimeEnd);
```

Now when I echo the `$assignedOn` and `$assignedend` variable then the minutes is showing different! Why?

## Echo

```
echo date('m/d/Y h:m:s',$assignedOn);
echo '<br/>';
echo date('m/d/Y h:m:s',$assignedEnd);
echo '<hr/>';
```

## Output Showing:

```
06/01/2018 02:06:00  
06/01/2018 04:06:00
```

The output time should be **02:01** and **04:02**.

Comment: 'm/d/Y H:i:s' try this

Comment: Oh. Yes, It's working :=)

Comment: Just to make @DsRaj answer crystal clear: Your problem is `m` doesnt refer to _minutes_ but to `Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros`. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for all the date format options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change format H:i:s

For print the minutes you need to i, as m is already reserved for the month

```
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$assignedOn);
echo '<br/>';
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s',$assignedEnd);
echo '<hr/>';
```

Answer (score 2):

because you are using `echo date('m/d/Y h:m:s',$assignedOn);` and m in php date refer to month, please change it to `echo date('m/d/Y h:i:s',$assignedOn);`